# Change color of td in a table that contains a + or -

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

So I have a table like this.

```
1    2    3    4    5
0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    -0
0    0    0    0    +0
0    0    0    0    0
```

I need the color of the text that contains a - to be changed to red and the color of the text that contains a + be turned into green.

I've tried giving the td a name and doing what's bellow

```
$('.status:contains("-")').css('color', 'red');
```

However I want it to search all td's and not have to give it a name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector as follows:

```js
$("td:contains(+)").css("color","green");
$("td:contains(-)").css("color","red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>-6</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>+5</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```